# O'Reilly template

Tags: templates

I don't know for you, but on my side, I'm a big fan of the O'Reilly book presentation.

I was wondering if some of you know where I could find a LaTeX template with the same presentation ?

Comment: I don't know for you but not all of us know what O'Reilly book format is.

Comment: O'Reilly is a publisher specialized in IT books. An example can be found here : http://it-ebooks.info/go.php?id=206-1365593918-226f5d06734ad7696b826f5ca370d3b7

Comment: @Nek So you want a template to produce a book (or whatever) that looks like those of O'Reilly? Then why don't you ask the publisher? If they don't give it to you directly, I don't think you will be able to get hold of it legally...

Comment: They use Docbook format, not LaTeX. Can't we "imitate" or "reproduce" that without being illegal ?

Comment: *I... must... resist... posting... this... link...* http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13186223#13186223 `:)`

Answer (score 21):

I tried to do something similar for a packtpub book and you can see the result: http://catalatex.blogspot.com.es/2013/08/llibre-de-format-actual.html

If you like it, feel free to adapt to your needs.

The PDF is here: https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnxjYXRhbGF0ZXg5fGd4Ojc2Mzk5ZTRmNTA2NzZiODI

The code is here: https://github.com/timkpaine/oreilly-latex-template

Comment: The links now seem to have expired.

Comment: It's true. I've moved PDF to: https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnxjYXRhbGF0ZXg5fGd4Ojc2Mzk5ZTRmNTA2NzZiODI and code: https://sites.google.com/site/catalatex9/home/documentclass/llibreactual/packtpub.tex?attredirects=0&d=1

Comment: https://github.com/timkpaine/oreilly-latex-template is the place to go now, it seems

Comment: An impressive work that exceeds mine. Thx Martin Capodici !

Comment: @jqueralt it's mostly the same, I added you as an owner when I made it, let me know if you need me to resend the invite link. Happy to transfer it back to its rightful owner